# Place title outside of GraphicsGrid in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I want to be able to place a text title centered just inside the bounding box generated by Manipulate yet above the `GraphicsGrid` and run boxes you see when executing the code. My stripped down code is

```
Manipulate[ 
 GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[{Rectangle[]}]}}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}],
 {{run, 0}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameLabel.html) option for `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[{Rectangle[]}]}}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}],
 {{run, 0}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, "Title goes here"}}]
```

[image: output]

To use the local `Manipulate` variables in the title you can wrap the title in `Dynamic`:

```
FrameLabel -> {{None, None},
               {None, Dynamic[ Row[{"Run: ", run}] ]}}
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I want to stylize the text in the title (say 16 pts, color, etc) without affecting the text throughout the frame. In particular, I added LabelStyle -> Directive[16], but this made the "run" text size 16 as well.

Comment: @Stephen play around with `Style["some text", 16]` There are some examples in the `FrameLabel` docs under Scope